# get query result as column not as row in mysql having multiple attributes for a product(pivot table)

Tags: php, mysql

I have this EAV data model

```
 products(prod_id, prod_name,...)
 attribute_key(attr_key_id, attr_name)
 attributes_values(attr_val_id, attr_key_id, value)
 product_attr_values(id,product_id,attr_val_id)
```

I having a product like a book, which can have multiple attribute like Author(can be multiple author for a book), Editor(can be multiple), publish year, Publisher etc.... There will be a search based on author in which i'm using below query and attached screenshot of query result.

*I am using the query below:*

```sql
SELECT p.prodname, f.attribute_name, v.value FROM products_ecomc AS p LEFT 
JOIN product_attribute_value AS t ON p.prodid = t.product_id 
LEFT JOIN attribute_value_ecomc AS v ON t.attribute_value_id = 
v.attr_value_id 
LEFT JOIN attr_common_flds_ecomc AS f ON v.attr_id = f.id 
WHERE 
t.product_id IN 
(
 SELECT 
 t.product_id 
 FROM 
 products_ecomc p 
 LEFT JOIN product_attribute_value t ON p.prodid = t.product_id 
 LEFT JOIN attribute_value_ecomc v ON t.attribute_value_id = v.attr_value_id 

 LEFT JOIN attr_common_flds_ecomc f ON v.attr_id = f.id 
 WHERE 
 ((f.attribute_name="Author" AND v.value="sabsyasachi das") 
 OR 
 (f.attribute_name="Author" AND v.value="Ela Datta")) 
 AND 
(p.subcatid IN (5,6,7,8,9,10)) GROUP BY t.product_id
 );
```

[Please find my query result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IK4kR.jpg)

*I want the result like below:*

```sql
prodname      |Aurhor1        | Aurhor2 |Editor1   |Editor2           |Place      
--------------|---------------|---------|----------|------------------|-------
Ramkinkar Baij|sabsyasachi das|Ela Datta|Sathi Basu|Radha Prasad Gupta|Panagarh
```

[Please find sqlfiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc65ed/1)

Thanks in advance please find a solution

Comment: I would do this transformation in php, not in sql because neither the keys, nor the values are unique. You can't use aggregate functions, nor just go by the keys.

Comment: @Shadow Can you give an example how could you transform this in php.

Comment: Give it a try first and let us know if you get stuck.

Comment: @Shadow can you see the problem? I have posted as an answer. Please find.